# Add Actions.scaleTo() to a Label in LibGDX

Tags: java, android, libgdx

In LibGDX, I want to make a text animation for my game. Therefore, I want that my labels gets larger with time. But if I use the `scaleTo()` method, nothing happens whereas other Actions like `moveTo()` work fine.

```
label1 = new Label("Test text", new Label.LabelStyle(font, Color.BLACK));
label2.addAction(Actions.parallel(Actions.moveTo(500, 300, 2.0f),Actions.scaleTo(0.1f, 0.1f,2.0f)));

label2 = new Label("Test text 2", new Label.LabelStyle(font, Color.BLACK));
label2.addAction(Actions.parallel(Actions.moveTo(500, 300, 2.0f),Actions.scaleTo(0.1f, 0.1f,2.0f)));

stage.addActor(label1);
stage.addActor(label2);
```

How can I make my labels scale? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can the person who downvoted justify his/her vote please? I know that I am a beginner but why is this question bad?

Comment: Call setTransform(true) on the label to enable scaling. Most widgets have it turned off by default because it causes Batch flushing.

Comment: setTransform() is a method of the class Group. Label doesn't extend from this Class. So the method is not available for a label...

Comment: Oh yeah, just a sec...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For performance reason most scene2d.ui groups have transform set to false by default.

For more detail you can check 
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d.ui#rotation-and-scale

If you want to scale, you can use Container which is useful for setting the size and alignment of a single widget.

```
private Container<Label> container;

@Override
public void create() {
    stage=new Stage();

    Label label1 = new Label("Test text", new Label.LabelStyle(font, Color.BLACK));

    container=new Container<Label>(label1);
    container.setTransform(true);   // for enabling scaling and rotation
    container.size(100, 60);
    container.setOrigin(container.getWidth() / 2, container.getHeight() / 2);
    container.setPosition(100,200);
    container.setScale(3);  //scale according to your requirement

    stage.addActor(container);
}

@Override
public void render() {
    super.render();

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1,1,1,1);
    gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    stage.draw();
    stage.act();
}
```

Add your Action on container instead of Label.

```
container.addAction(Actions.parallel(Actions.moveTo(500, 300, 2.0f),Actions.scaleTo(0.1f, 0.1f,2.0f)));
```

Answer (score 2):

Labels don't directly support scaling. The easy way to solve this is put the label in a Container, `setTransform(true)` on the Container, and add your scale action to the Container.