# How do i scale a Label in LibGdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx

i am trying to code a HUD for my game but i cannot figure out how to scale a Label properly I am using this code:

```
Label hpLabel = new Label("HP: ",new Label.LabelStyle(new BitmapFont(),Color.BROWN));
    table.add(hpLabel);
    viewport = new FitViewport(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/ FacultyWars.PPM, Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/ FacultyWars.PPM, cam);
    stage = new Stage(viewport, batch);
    stage.addActor(table);
//other ellements added after this
```

The HP tag is enormous on the screen. I tried using setScale on the label and on the table to no avail. Any help is appreciated!
Thanks

Here is a picture of the current screen https://gyazo.com/57c190a9d7516bb8b2256bf1a7d17b4c

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add Actions.scaleTo() to a Label in LibGDX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42404452/add-actions-scaleto-to-a-label-in-libgdx)

Comment: Answers there don't seem to work for me even though the question is similar.

Comment: Can you clarify "don't seem to work"? Hard to help otherwise.

Comment: When i try with the container, it displays nothing. Tried different scalings to no avail. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Simply add the Label to a Group then apply the scale to the group.

```
    Label label = new Label("hello", skin);
    Group group = new Group();
    group.addActor(label);
    group.setScale(2f, 2f);
```

I only scale Groups with Labels in animations where at the end of the animation the scale is 1. One should not scale fonts, because it looks pixelated. For example, a simple scale up scale down animation:

```
group.addAction(Actions.sequence(Actions.scaleTo(2f, 2f, 1f), Actions.scaleTo(1f, 1f, 1f)));
```

Answer (score 5):

Use setFontScale(float fontScale) method of Label

Comment: It "kinda" works. I can scale it down to a certain size which is still too big and the text is really pixelated. If i try to scale it down even further it just dissapears. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you should just use a smaller texture? Do you ever need this big labels? To avoid the texture being pixelated you should Change the Filtersettings of this texture

Comment: What do you mean by change of Filtersettings? Any links?

Comment: quite old topic, but yes: [link](https://www.pixnbgames.com/blog/tratamiento-imagenes/how-to-smooth-textures-when-they-are-resized-in-libgdx-filters-i/)