# Using Actions on a Button-LibGdx

Tags: libgdx

I have a play button like this;

```
    private void drawPlayButton() {
        playButton = new ImageButton(new TextureRegionDrawable(playTexture), new TextureRegionDrawable(pressTexture));
        stage.addActor(playButton);

        playButton.setPosition(UIConstants.PLAY_X, UIConstants.PLAY_Y, Align.center);

        playButton.addListener(new ActorGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public void tap(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int count, int button) {
                super.tap(event, x, y, count, button);

                game.setScreen(new GameScreen(game));

            }
        });
    }
```

I want to add scale in and out effect to this button using Actions.

I am not that familiar with Actions,I tried something like this;

```
float duationsec= 0.5f;
playButton.addAction(Actions.sequence(Actions.scaleBy(0.2f,0.2f,duationsec),    
Actions.scaleTo(1f, 1f, duationsec)));
img.setOrigin(Align.center);
stage.addActor(playButton);
```

But this is not giving any effect to the button also same code works for an Image.Is this because button uses drawable texture?

How can I give this effect to a button using Actions?

Also my code is working for one time only.I am calling it in show().If I call it in render(),it works in an abnormal manner.I want this effect to be displaying forever.

Is it possible to achieve this?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This link contains the similar question and answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42404452/add-actions-scaleto-to-a-label-in-libgdx]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For performance reason most `scene2d.ui` groups have `transform` set to false by default and `ImageButton` is part of that ui group so you've to enable transform by using `setTransform(..)` method.

For more detail you can check 
https://libgdx.com/wiki/graphics/2d/scene2d/scene2d-ui#rotation-and-scale

```
float duationsec= 0.5f;

playButton.setOrigin(Align.center);
playButton.setTransform(true);             //  <--  Enable Transform
stage.addActor(playButton);
playButton.addAction(Actions.sequence(Actions.scaleBy(0.2f,0.2f,duationsec),Actions.scaleTo(1f, 1f, duationsec)));
```

**EDIT**

If you want to scale up/down on user Click, Do in this way :

```
playButton.addListener(new ClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {

            playButton.addAction(Actions.sequence(Actions.scaleBy(0.2f,0.2f,duationsec),Actions.scaleTo(1f, 1f, duationsec), Actions.run(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    game.setScreen(new GameScreen(game));
                }
            })));

            super.clicked(event, x, y);
        }
    });
```

Comment: After enabling transform also no effect.

Comment: where you want to apply action on `playButton` ?

Comment: I wanted that effect to be displayed forever on the button .I referred this question and made it work. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42404452/add-actions-scaleto-to-a-label-in-libgdx]. After using container,it worked.

Comment: I've spent few hours trying to figure it out. Thanks a lot!